# Learning bubble sort

Tags: java, arrays, bubble-sort

My code is working but when I execute the code the final element of the array is not sorting and it display unchanged plz help me.

```
package array;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements: ");
        int numOf=in.nextInt();

        int array1[]=new int[numOf];

        for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
            System.out.println("Insert the "+(i+1)+" element of the array: ");
            array1[i]=in.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("The inserted array is:");
        for(int j=0;j<array1.length;j++){
            System.out.print(array1[j]+" ");
        }

        int temp=0;
        for(int k=0;k<array1.length;k++){
            for(int z=1;z<(array1.length-1);z++){
                if(array1[z-1]>array1[z]){

                    temp=array1[z-1];
                    array1[z-1]=array1[z];
                    array1[z]=temp;
                }
            }           
        }
        System.out.println("Sorted array");
        for(int c=0;c<array1.length;c++){
            System.out.print(array1[c]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn to debug.  Either run an debugger, or at least print out the whole array for inspection after each loop, so you can see how your array is changing

Comment: change (array1.length-1) to (array1.length-k)

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct sorting loop as below:

```
for (int k = 0; k < array1.length-1; k++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < array1.length-k-1; z++) {
            if (array1[z] > array1[z+1]) {
                temp = array1[z];
                array1[z] = array1[z+1];
                array1[z+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it should be like 
`for(int z=1;z<(array.length-k);z++);`

Comment: array1.length-k-1 is  correct as we compare z with z+1 so z+1 cover last element.

Answer (score 0):

When you see an "off by one error" look in your code where you are looping over conditions that either start or end 1 more or less from the boundaries.

In this case I would look carefully at this line

```
for(int z=1;z<(array1.length-1); z++)
```

why is it `length -1`

Comment: Thanks and I know I figured it out it should be like 
` for(int z=1;z<(array.length-k);z++);` ryt.